# Can I create a global variable for this?

Tags: objective-c

```
// This is the line which retrieves the current image on the UIView
CGImageRef originalImage = imageView.image.CGImage;
```

I declare this in a method I use to edit my image which can be called by several buttons.

Is there anyway I can declare this variable globally so it always holds the first image loaded in the UIView? I can then use a copy variable to do all the editing on e.g.

```
CGImageRef copyImage = originalImage;
```

I have tried to make it global by declaring it in the header file and instantiate it in the method file however when I try and access the global variable in another method it is as if it hasn't been made global.

Any advice or better solutions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Have you set the `@property` in the header file like. `@property (nonatomic, strong) CGImageRef originalImage;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not entirely clear what you are trying to do, but what I would point out is:

1. the assignment

   ```
             CGImageRef copyImage = originalImage;
   ```

   will not create a copy of your image; it will simply give you a local variable pointing to the same image as `originalImage`; if you modify `copyImage`, you also modify `originalImage`;
2. if you want to make a copy of an CGImage so that you can modify it freely while keeping the original safe, use:

   ```
         CGImageRef img1 = CGImageCreateCopy(img2);
   ```
3. if you want to save your original image as under point 2, simply add a property to your class and initialize it soon after you have got your CGImage in place (e.g., in `viewDidLoad`:

   ```
          -(void) viewDidLoad {
              ...
              self.originalImage = CGImageCreateCopy(imageView.image.CGImage);
              ...
          }
   ```

`self.originalImage` will be your original image, while you will be able to freely modify `imageView.image.CGImage`.

Don't forget to release the copied image in your dealloc method.

Hope this helps.

Comment: This does help however I am having issues with scope (I coded in Java previously so objective c is some what different). I can't seem to create a global variable of originalImage so that the copyImage in a method can have access to the originalImage as you stated. I tried making a property of the CGImageRef however it brings up an error. I even tried making a class variable by making it static however it appears this is both frowned upon and it never solved my problem regardless.

Comment: you do not need a global variable; a normal class member will do. post your code to define a property and the error you get...

Comment: I was trying - @property (nonatomic,retain) CGImageRef originalImage;   Error - property with retain or strong attribute must be of object type.

Comment: use: `@property (nonatomic,assign)` -- in `dealloc`: `CGImageRefRelease(self.originalImage);` -- be sure not to override the variable without releasing its current value, otherwise you will leak memory.

Comment: It seems to be compiling, i'll test whether I can get the original image displayed if a restore button is pressed. I have ARC on which means I can't release objects is this advisable? or should I have it off and manage memory myself?

Comment: if you have ARC on, `assign` or `retain` will fail; use `weak` in place of `assign`. as to releasing, it's ok: CoreGraphics objects (CG...) are not managed by ARC, you have to do it on your own.

Comment: Assign seems to be working ok(If I change it to weak it errors with -attribute must be of object type), I haven't released it though should I do that in the ViewDidUnload method to prevent memory leaks? Every problem I had seems to solved other than that. Thanks a lot! I'm unsure why when I edit a picture taken/picked from the library it seems to rotate the image automatically, had any similar experience? if not thanks for all your help regardless :)

Comment: viewDidUnload is a good place to release the image. as to rotation, I have no idea. glad to have helped!